# Flask UWSGI ModuleNotFound

Tags: flask, import, uwsgi, flask-httpauth

I have a Flask application that I'm trying to configure for a production environment. So far, during testing `python app.py` inside of a virtualenv works fine.

However, I'm beginning to configure the application to begin using UWSGI. When I attempt to start the Flask app using

`$ uwsgi -s /tmp/myapplication.sock --manage-script-name --mount /myapplication=app:app
 --virtualenv /path/to/my/venv`

I get a

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_httpauth'

I was wondering if anyone has experience w/ that authentication module and if they have any advice on what I should do. I'm unsure of why the development server starts without an issue, but the uwsgi server (that I pass the same virtualenv that's used for the dev server) runs into import issues

Comment: Check that you've installed `flask_httpauth` in your virtual environment.

Comment: @Fian Is there something special I need to do for that? I did a pip install in the virtual env, and as I said it runs w/ `python`, so I'm assuming it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by setting the `home` path to my virtualenv directory (`.venv` in my case):

```
# uwsgi.ini
home = /Users/floatingrock/Desktop/projects/google_v2/.venv/
```

If you're wondering, I got the full path using `pwd`.